# How to find the actual IP address of a Cent OS virtual machine?

Tags: hadoop, virtual-machine, ifconfig

[image]

Hi, I have installed Cent OS inside VM Ware. I want to know the IP address. When I try to find it using "ifconfig" in terminal, it is showing Local address(127.0.0.1). What might be the issue? I want to know the actual IP address.

Comment: I shutdown the guest OS and VM Ware and again restarted. Now it's giving the actual ip address(192.XXX.XXX.XX). Don't know the exact reason for this behaviour!

Comment: @Idos.Ya sure.I am new to this. I will do it from now onwards. Actually I tried both the solutions. But they didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `ip a s` or `ifconfig -a`

What you see if the address of the localhost interface, it seems your VM doesn't have any ethXXX of emXXX interface configured

Answer (score 0):

Try running [`dhclient`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/dhclient) `eth0` first, as `dhclient` is used to get an IP address from a DHCP server.
Then run `ifconfig` and you will see the `IPv4/IPv6` (`inet addr` and `inet6 addr` respectively) that has been assigned to your VM.